# passing variables as arguments using child_process exec from index.js firebase cloud function to python script

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to pass the userId variable from the firebase cloud function "myPapp" in my index.js file to a python script that runs using child_process. However, i don't think the variable is being passed properly to the python script because the userId is null in the python script.

Here is the code in my index.js file:

```
const {exec} = require("child_process");

exports.myPapp = functions.database
    .ref("/users/{userId}/messages/{pushId}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const userId = context.params.userId;

      if (userId != null) {
        console.error("The user is authenticated.");

        process.env["PYTHONPATH"] = "./lib/";
        
        const command = `python3 ./app.py ${userId}`;

        exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
            return;
          }
          console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
          console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        });

      } else {
        console.error("The user is not authenticated.");
      }
    });
```

in the python script file app.py i am using sys.argv[1] to call the argument:

```
import sys

userId = sys.argv[1]

ref = db.reference(f"/users/{userId}/messages")
```

However, the userId is null.

is there another way to do this or am i missing something?

Comment: It's not clear how you are observing the results. The python you're showing doesn't seem to print anything. I suggest making the example code here as small and clear as possible so that anyone can copy it and easily reproduce the same behavior.

Comment: Also I will point out that your function doesn't return a promise that indicates when all the async work is complete, so it could have other strange behavior.